# Any App Engine boilerplates available to save time on basic features?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

Are the any projects that provide basic features for building an app using a webapp2 including: signup, login, logout, sessions, and anything that will save development time and preferable Jinja2 for templates and python 2.7

I know of two ([1](https://github.com/coto/gae-boilerplate), [2](https://github.com/metachris/appengine-boilerplate)) but I'm looking for alternatives.

Comment: I am the creator of the first option for you are looking alternatives. I don't want to encourage you to use,  but I would love to hear why it doesn't works for you.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Look at this. With everything that may be you need, templates, user registration, etc, etc

http://www.github.com/coto/gae-boilerplate

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.

https://github.com/fredrikbonander/Webapp2-Sample-Applications

Comment: Thanks, but that looks like a near clone of the first example I posted. I'm now looking at EngineAuth, looks promising.

Comment: Regarding Auth there has been a detailed discussion here,https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/webapp2/Ui5FEFVnyIY , EngineAuth is not actively being developed so it would be better to stick to webapp2, even Guido himself is involved in it so I think it will be good for long term.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **Not VanillAE**
http://notvanillae.appspot.com

It's Webapp2, Jinja2 and Python 2.7. It includes decorators for trivializing caching, user authentication and authorization for Google APIs.

It also builds in some excellent front-end jazz, including Twitter Bootstrap and PJAX.js.

Comment: I like a lot of the tools, but it may be overkill for some projects.  Can this be customized like Bootstrap to only download the components that you want?

Comment: @BrentWashburne The way it's been built makes it trivial to remove any bits you don't want. I do like the idea of a customizer though. Please post an issue on the GitHub project. In the meantime, if there's specific tools you want to remove let me know and I'll add instructions to the docs.